# <p:calendar> don't show in my page

Tags: jsf, primefaces, calendar

I have the below calendar:

```
<p:calendar id="startDate" value="#{myBean.startDate}" showOn="button"
            pattern =" dd ,MM, yyyy" locale="en"
            required="true" >
    <p:ajax event="dateSelect"  />
</p:calendar>
```

However, it doesn't show up as a calendar:

[image]

How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: For web development starters, if anything appears to be failing in client side, just press F12 in webbrowser and check console. Any clues there? See also http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info for more hints.

Comment: Which JFS Components library are you using? Exist all css and js stuff for that widget in the html output?

Comment: @ReneM. apparently he is using Primefaces ... and yep, I would recommend checking the console errors as BalusC said